# Call one function in both controller - AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers

user.controller.js:

```
const fetchApi = () => {
  console.log('fetching');
};

fetchApi();
```

I want to call this function in my dashboard.controller.js without writing this same hard code in dashboard controller again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

var fetchApi = function($scope){
   console.log("fetching");
};
fetchApi.$inject = ['$scope'];
app.controller('homeCtrl', fetchApi);
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', fetchApi);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="dashboardCtrl"></div>
<div ng-controller="homeCtrl"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT : inject service

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

var fetchApi = function($scope, RestService){
 console.log("fetching");
 RestService.getUser();
};
fetchApi.$inject = ['$scope', 'RestService'];
app.controller('homeCtrl', fetchApi);
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', fetchApi);

app.service('RestService', ['$http',
 function($http){
    this.getUser = function() {
        //$http api call
        console.log("get user");
    }
 }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="dashboardCtrl"></div>
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is this called "service" ?

Comment: No, This so not a service . is a simple controller function.
for service https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: Can you update your answer with services approach? i am looking for service method.